# How do I display deals data for each game fetched

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a website that is using the cheapshark api. Currently I it works on the home tab where it displays some deals. I'm working on the search function where the users enters a title like "batman" and all the batman games pop up. I made an "accordion" where I would display other deals for the game too but for that I would need to make another api call on the endpoint "https://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/games?id=612" where id needs to be dynamic. I want it to behave like this. So when the user searches for a game like "batman" and all the batman related games pop up. I want it to be like it maps through all the games that popped up and gets the deals for them so I can display the data.

Here's the code I have:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { AnimatedPage } from '../../components/navbar/AnimatedPage'
import '../../scss/search.scss'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import { Accordion } from '../../components/navbar/Accordion'

export const Search = () => {

  const [gameTitle, setGameTitle] = useState("")
  const [hasRefetched, setHasRefetched] = useState(false)

  const { data: game, isLoading, refetch, isFetching } = useQuery(["game"], async () => {
    return axios.get(`https://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/games?title=${gameTitle}`).then((res) => res.data)
  })

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setGameTitle(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter" || e.key === "Go") {
      refetch()
      setHasRefetched(true)
    }
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h1>is Loading</h1>
  }

  if (isFetching) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>
  }

  return (
    <AnimatedPage>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='input-wrapper'>
          <h2>Search for a specific title</h2>
          <input type="text" onChange={handleInput} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} />
          <button onClick={refetch}>refetch</button>
        </div>

        <div className='games-wrapper'>
          {game && game.length > 0 ? (
            game.map((game) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <div className='search-game-card'>
                    <Accordion game={game}/>
                  </div>
                </>
              )
            })
          ) : (hasRefetched ? <p id='data-error'>No results found</p> : null)
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </AnimatedPage>
  )
}
```

As of the time I uploaded this the api doesn't work for me because I tried some code from chatgpt and I'm guessing it made too many api calls and it crashed the thing for me. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance! :)

The website link is https://gametag.netlify.app/

I tried a few things and I'm kind of burned out because of all this. I tried some chatgpt and blackbox solutions which did not work at all.